# Oracle left outer join: howto limit requests in right table

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join

I have a large statement:

```
SELECT
    a.user_id, a.user_name,
    s.name, s.value,
    d.default
FROM
    accounts a,
    settings s
    LEFT OUTER JOIN default d ON ( d.name = s.name )
WHERE
    s.user_id = a.user_id;
```

The problem is that `settings` contains a large amount of entries and I need to pick the one with the highest ID. I can imagine do change the statement and replace the join with a subselect (which grabs the correct entry from `settings`), but I'm curious to see if there is a better solution. Any input is appreciated. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a sub-query to get just the results you want out of the right table.

Something like:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    accounts a,
    (
      SELECT
          user_id,
          *
      FROM
          settings
      WHERE
          RANK() OVER (ORDER BY id DESC, PARTITION BY user_id) = 1
    ) s
```

Comment: Windowed function can't be used in WHERE clause.

Comment: Oh, really?  Ok, in a sub select then, 1 sec.

Answer (score -1):

getting the highest ID from a table could be done with a

```
select max(id) ...
```

or with a

```
select id from settings where rownum=1 order by id desc
```

(i prefer the first solution)
or just like John proposed, but you'll need a subquery anyway.
One more thing, there might be some typo in your example, i don't see where d is coming from, neither the point of making an auto left join...

Here is what I would have written

```
SELECT
    user_id, user_name,
    name, value,
    default
FROM
    accounts join 
    (select user_id,name 
     from settings 
     where RANK() OVER (ORDER BY id DESC, PARTITION BY user_id) = 1) using(user_id)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN default using ( name )
```

... still subquery

Comment: Thanks, corrected the example in regard to the default / d table.

Comment: Your last query will not reliably return the expected results, because `rownum=1` will be evaluated before `order by user_id desc`.

Comment: That's right, thank you, I would use the piece of code proposed by John then   : RANK() OVER (ORDER BY id DESC, PARTITION BY user_id) = 1.